# $T$ bounded linear, show $A_2T=TA_1$ for $A_2, A_1$ compact

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $T:H_1 \to H_2$ be a bounded linear map between two infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces and suppose that $T$ is both surjective and injective. Let $A_2 \in K(H_2)$ (where $K(H)$ denotes the set of all compact linear operators on $H$). Show that there is a compact linear operator $A_1 \in K(H_2)$ such that $A_2T=TA_1$.

I'm not really sure how to start this problem at all. I believe that $A_2T$ and $TA_1$ are both compact operators themselves. I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, though. Any suggestions on where to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hilbert spaces are Banach spaces. Since $T$ is bounded and bijective, that means, by the open mapping theorem, it is open. As $T$ is a bijection, there is a unique linear $A_1 = T^{-1}A_2 T\colon H_1 \to H_1$ such that $A_2 T = T A_1$.

The only other demand (which may already be clear, depending on your background) is that $A_1$ still be compact. In case it's not, let $S \subset H_1$ be bounded. Then $T(S)$ is bounded, so $A_2 T(S)$ is relatively compact. Since $T^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, $A_1(S) = T^{-1}A_2 T(S)$ is relatively compact as well.

Answer (score 2):

As $T$ is bijective and bounded, it is invertible (because a Hilbert space is a Banach space and so the open mapping theorem applies). So we can define $A_1=T^{-1}A_2T$.